# Create Form in DLL using C++Builder

Tags: dll, c++builder, vcl

I want to create a DLL that exports a function that will show a Form to the user.  Does the VCL allow this use, and if so, then how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick Answer: Yes

Create a DLL in the IDE, ensure that you have selected to use VCL in the DLL creation wizard.  Again, in the IDE, add a new VCL Form.  You then have to create a function callable from outside the DLL to create the form and show it.

Comment: Do I have to call Application->Initialize() and Application->Run() and if so then when?

Comment: No, those are called in the EXE. However, if you compile the DLL to be self-contained (no Dynamic RTL, no Runtime Packages), then it will have its own `Application` object, it will not share or interact with the EXE's `Application` object. Depending on what your Form does, it might be enough to just pass the EXE's `Application->Handle` to the DLL so it can be assigned to its `Application->Handle`. However, to actually share the EXE's `Application` object, you need to enable Runtime Packages in both EXE and DLL, and then distribute the RTL's BPL files with your app.